# trying to output the json value in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Using value, value_classification, and timestamp values in json data
I am trying to print as a solid gauge of Highcharts.

The values in series data are inserted as blank values.

What's the problem?

```
{
    "name": "Fear and Greed Index",
    "data": [
        {
            "value": "27",
            "value_classification": "Fear",
            "timestamp": "21-12-2021",
            "time_until_update": "-1639979045"
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "error": null
    }
}
```

Using that value,
I am trying to complete the solid gauge of Highcharts.

Highcharts Demos › Solid gauge
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid

The code I've tried so far is below.

HTML

```
<div id="container-speed" class="chart-container"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function () {
    var processedData = [];

    $.getJSON("https://api.alternative.me/fng/?date_format=en", function (json) {
             for (i = 1; i > json.length; i++){
                     processedData.push(json[i].value);
             }

             var gaugeOptions = {
              chart: {
                type: 'solidgauge'
              },

              title: null,

              pane: {
                center: ['50%', '85%'],
                size: '140%',
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                background: {
                  backgroundColor:
                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || '#EEE',
                  innerRadius: '60%',
                  outerRadius: '100%',
                  shape: 'arc'
                }
              },

              exporting: {
                enabled: false
              },

              tooltip: {
                enabled: false
              },

              // the value axis
              yAxis: {
                stops: [
                  [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                  [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                  [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
                ],
                lineWidth: 0,
                tickWidth: 0,
                minorTickInterval: null,
                tickAmount: 2,
                title: {
                  y: -70
                },
                labels: {
                  y: 16
                }
              },

              plotOptions: {
                solidgauge: {
                  dataLabels: {
                    y: 5,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                  }
                }
              }
            };

             // The speed gauge
            var chartSpeed = Highcharts.chart('container-speed', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
              yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 200,
                title: {
                  text: 'test'
                }
              },

              credits: {
                enabled: false
              },

              series: [{
                name: 'test',
                data: processedData,
                dataLabels: {
                  format:
                    '<div style="text-align:center">' +
                    '<span style="font-size:25px">{y}</span><br/>' +
                    '<span style="font-size:12px;opacity:0.4">km/h</span>' +
                    '</div>'
                }
              }]

            }));

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Check if processedData outputs something.

Mistake: Looping over json data is incorrect as the response is an object and not an array.
Create an IIFE and verify the first part then move ahead with chart creation.
eg.

```
$(function () {
    var processedData = [];

    $.getJSON("https://api.alternative.me/fng/?date_format=en", function (json) {
            // wrong
             for (i = 1; i > json.length; i++){
                     processedData.push(json[i].value);
             }
    });
    console.log(processedData);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint.As you wrote, it is also output as an empty value in console.log. What problem do you have?

Comment: Please go through 
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/180/how-to-iterate-over-an-object-with-javascript-and-jquery-optimally

Above will help you find your mistake.
Another hint: var obj = {};
obj.length will not give its length as we do in array.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce your code and receive the data using this approach:

```
fetch("https://api.alternative.me/fng/?date_format=en")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(output => {
    const chartData = output.data.map(d => parseFloat(d.value))
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s1fczwj0/